# Cannot resolve method onAttach() in SQLiteOpenHelper

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-fragments

**I am trying to call a method (createButton in HomeFragment) from a class that extends SQLiteOpenHelper**. I am using getSupportFragmentManager to open this fragment and so I need to pass context to use this getSupportFragmentManager without errors. I have tried using context in this way:

```
private FragmentActivity myContext;

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    myContext=(FragmentActivity) context;
    super.onAttach(context);
}

public void buttonCreator(Drawable d,String a) {

    Log.d("tag_name", "buttonCreator" + myContext);

    HomeFragment homeFragment = (HomeFragment)myContext.getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments().get(1);
    homeFragment.createButton(d, a);
}
```

But I get an error when calling "super.onAttach(context)", that the method onAttach() cannot be resolved. **Is there a way I can use onAttach() in SQLiteOpenHelper so that I can access getSupportFragmentManager to open my fragment?**

I have also tried accessing context this way:
But when I do this it "cannot resolve method 'getSupportFragmentManager()'"

```
private Context mContext;


public DatabaseStructure(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    Log.d("tag_name", "Entered DatabaseStructure" + context);
    mContext = context;
} 

    public void buttonCreator(Drawable d,String a) {

    Log.d("tag_name", "buttonCreator" + myContext);

    HomeFragment homeFragment = (HomeFragment)mContext.getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments().get(1);
    homeFragment.createButton(d, a);
}
```

Here is the full class code:

```
public class DatabaseStructure extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

// Database Version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "database";

// Table Names
private static final String DB_TABLE = "table_image";

// column names
private static final String KEY_NAME = "image_name";
private static final String KEY_IMAGE = "image_data";


// Table create statement
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_IMAGE = "CREATE TABLE " + DB_TABLE + "("+
        KEY_NAME + " TEXT," +
        KEY_IMAGE + " BLOB);";


private Context mContext;


public DatabaseStructure(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    Log.d("tag_name", "Entered DatabaseStructure" + context);
    mContext = context;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // creating table
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_IMAGE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // on upgrade drop older tables
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DB_TABLE);

    // create new table
    onCreate(db);
}

public void addEntry( String name, byte[] image) throws SQLiteException {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Log.d("tag_name", "Enter Add Entry" + db);
    ContentValues cv = new  ContentValues();
    cv.put(KEY_NAME,    name);
    cv.put(KEY_IMAGE, image);
    db.insert(DB_TABLE, null, cv);
}



public boolean checkDatabase() {

    Log.d("tag_name", "In CheckDatabase method" );

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor mCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DB_TABLE, null);


    if (mCursor.moveToFirst())
    {

        mCursor.moveToFirst();
        String appName = mCursor.getString(0);
        byte[] image = mCursor.getBlob(1);


        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.length);
        Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(Resources.getSystem(), bitmap);
        //Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);

        buttonCreator(d, appName);


        return true;

    } else
    {


        return false;
    }

}



private FragmentActivity myContext;

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    myContext=(FragmentActivity) context;
    super.onAttach(context);
}




public void buttonCreator(Drawable d,String a) {

    Log.d("tag_name", "buttonCreator" + myContext);

    HomeFragment homeFragment = (HomeFragment)myContext.getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments().get(1);
    homeFragment.createButton(d, a);
}
}
```

Comment: I understood nothing how this code relates to `SQLiteOpenHelper`. Can u post full classes? Just remove methods that not needed for this topic.

Comment: Why would you want to do anything related to views from a class whose only responsibility is to manage a database? Usually it's the other way around.

Comment: @ghostman I posted the full Activity, which extends SQLiteOpenHelper.

Comment: @Natalie уже ответили)

Comment: @EugenPechanec I am saving an image and string in a database, based on a user action. Then I want to check if the database is empty or not. If it is  not empty I want to open a new activity and pass it the values stored in the database. Is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: This for example: `if(dbHelper.checkDatabase()) { buttonCreator(d, appName); }` Move `buttonCreator` method to where it's actually used. That way database helper doesn't need to know anything about what for is the result of `checkDatabase` used.

Answer (score 3):

`onAttach()` is the `Fragment`'s callback method which you may override for attaching listeners or other stuff in your fragment class.

By what you said, you extend your class from `SQLiteOpenHelper` and thus you don't have any `onAttach()` method to override.
So the answer to

> Is there a way I can use onAttach() in `SQLiteOpenHelper` so that I can
>   access getSupportFragmentManager to open my fragment?

-- 
**NO**.

Also, regarding how you can get context, I don't know why you are extending your class to `SQLiteOpenHelper` but if you want to get context to start your fragment or use `getSupportFragmentManager()`, you can pass the context in that class when you create its object.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. You say "you can pass the context in that class when you create its object". But how can I pass context so I don't get context=null?

Comment: You have run activity, get context from it

Comment: But you should open database connection when your fragment attached. The best way you can use Loader to work with database in background.